# cygwin install FGSL?

Tags: cygwin, gfortran

I use gfortran on cygwin and want to install the FGSL package, then I try

```
xxx@xxx-PC ~ 
$wget http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/download/fgsl-1.0.0.tar.gz
$tar zxvf fgsl-1.0.0.tar.gz
$cd fgsl-1.0.0
$./configure
```

so far so good, then what next should I do?
https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran:_FGSL

My apologies. Under Vladimir's guidance, I try

```
xxx@xxx-PC ~/fgsl-1.0.0
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0   -o libfgsl.la -rpath /usr/local/lib fgsl.lo libfgsl_la-fgsl_utils.lo -lgsl -lgslcblas -lblas
/usr/bin/grep: /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libblas.la' is not a valid libtool archive
Makefile:531: recipe for target 'libfgsl.la' failed
make[2]: *** [libfgsl.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
Makefile:636: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
Makefile:437: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and

```
xxx@xxx-PC ~/fgsl-1.0.0
$ make install
Making install in .
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0   -o libfgsl.la -rpath /usr/local/lib fgsl.lo libfgsl_la-fgsl_utils.lo -lgsl -lgslcblas -lblas
/usr/bin/grep: /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libblas.la' is not a valid libtool archive
Makefile:531: recipe for target 'libfgsl.la' failed
make[1]: *** [libfgsl.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/CygwinWorkshop/fgsl-1.0.0'
Makefile:636: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Some errors that I don't know how to handle occur.

According to the hints by screen, I next check

```
$ apt-cyg install lapack
Package lapack is already installed, skipping
$ apt-cyg install liblapack-devel
Package liblapack-devel is already installed, skipping
```

A fortran code named bsp.f03 given by https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran:_FGSL
is used for testing purpose

```
program bsp
  use fgsl
  implicit none

  real( kind = fgsl_double ) :: a
  real( kind = fgsl_double ) :: d = 5.0_fgsl_double

  a = d ** 2 * m_pi_4

  write( *, * ) "Kreisflaeche = ", a
end program bsp
```

then I compile and link

```
$g95 bsp.f03 -I/usr/local/include/g95 -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lfgsl_g95 -lgslcblas
-bash: g95: command not found
```

I use R for statistical 
computing on windows a lot and I'm a total newcomer to fortran and cygwin, so please forgive my very basic and naive questions about the above.

Comment: Try `make`, `make install` and then use it as any other library. You have to be more specific if you have any particular problem.

Comment: My apologies. Under your guidance, I've re-edited my questions .

Comment: Do you have BLAS installed? If yes, in which directory?

Comment: Ok,I'll try it. Previously,I think it's unnesessary to install BLAS since I've installed Lapack already. As your advised,I'll install BLAS according to [software_cygwin_libraries](http://www.columbia.edu/~kt2347/index.html?page=software_cygwin_libraries). Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait, in your last command you have `g95`. You should have `gfortran` there, shouldn't you? BLAS is requires for Lapack and has to be installed separately.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I also tried gfortran, and still sth wrong of lib stuffs come out. Eventually, I decide to use lapack as well as [Alan Miller's Fortran Software](http://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/) instead of FGSL. Tks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the configure step.The source package was configured for a different system.

In general, for any build, you should run

```
autoreconf -ivf
./configure
make
```

In addition before these steps, replace in Makefile.am

```
libfgsl_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info @LIB_CURRENT@:@LIB_REVISION@:@LIB_AGE@ @FGSL_LDFLAGS@
```

with

```
libfgsl_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info @LIB_CURRENT@:@LIB_REVISION@:@LIB_AGE@ @FGSL_LDFLAGS@ -no-undefined
```

to build the shared library.

Comment: Tks. I follow your steps and sth wrong with the last make step `/usr/bin/grep: /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libblas.la: No such file or directory
libtool:   error: '/usr/lib/libblas.la' is not a valid libtool archive
` I do install BLAS-3.6.0 following [link](http://www.columbia.edu/~kt2347/index.html?page=software_cygwin_libraries), but I don't know how to get the so-called libblas.la file. Besides, if I install FGSL succefully, how should I complie and link a f90 file (e.g.  a foo.f90) using gfortran and FGSL in cygwin @matzeri

Comment: install liblapack-devel package. It includes BLAS and LAPACK headers and import library.   /usr/lib/libblas.la is not used anymore and it should not be present. The instruction you are using are obsolete for blas and lapack, the package for 3.6.0 are already available from cygwin setup

Comment: I do have installed the  liblapack-devel package, `$ apt-cyg install liblapack-devel    Package liblapack-devel is already installed, skipping`, in fact, I've installed all packages in categories Base，Devel，Libs，Net，System，Utils , Editors, Math and Science .

Comment: a bit of overkill. Are you sure to have run all the 3 steps "autoreconf -ivf;
./configure ; make" in the source directory ?

Comment: Yes, I did. As you suggested, first I replaced in Makefile.am `libfgsl_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info @LIB_CURRENT@:@LIB_REVISION@:@LIB_AGE@ @FGSL_LDFLAGS@` with `libfgsl_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info @LIB_CURRENT@:@LIB_REVISION@:@LIB_AGE@ @FGSL_LDFLAGS@ -no-undefined`,  then I ran three steps`autoreconf -ivf ./configure make`. You said `/usr/lib/libblas.la is not used anymore and it should not be present`, but in files Makefile, Makefile.am, Makefile.in there exsit commands `lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfgsl.la` , and what they are used for?

Comment: `lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfgsl.la` is part of the build procedure. That is fine. Check  if you have libblas.la reported in system directories with `grep libblas.la /usr/lib/*.la` and `grep libblas.la /usr/local/lib/*.la` . If so  remove/rename those files containing it.

Comment: Tks again, I'll try it. `grep libblas.la /usr/lib/*.la` gives me `/usr/lib/libgsl.la:dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/libblas.la' /usr/lib/libgslcblas.la:dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/libblas.la' /usr/lib/libqrupdate.la:dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/liblapack.la /usr/lib/libblas.la` and `grep libblas.la /usr/local/lib/*.la` displays  `grep: /usr/local/lib/*.la: No such file or directory`. Thus, as you suggested, I should remove/rename files `libgsl.la`, `/libgslcblas.la` and `libqrupdate.la`

Comment: Yes move them away from `/usr/lib`. I removed libqrupdate.la some time ago [link](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-11/msg00055.html)  so you don't seem to have an updated cygwin install. On my system `$ grep blas  /usr/lib/libgsl.la` gives 
`dependency_libs=' -lblas'`